# Flatpicker configuration with "showMonths:2" display wrong month calendar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, flatpickr

I tried to change the configuration of flatpickr in my asp.net mvc 4 project to display two months for with mode range, however i get this result :
[flatpickr-range-selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvrdG.png)

what can be the reason for that  !?

```html
 <input id="test" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.9/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.css" integrity="sha512-MQXduO8IQnJVq1qmySpN87QQkiR1bZHtorbJBD0tzy7/0U9+YIC93QWHeGTEoojMVHWWNkoCp8V6OzVSYrX0oQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script>
        let flatPickrBegin = flatpickr('#test', {
             mode:'range',
            showMonths: 2  
        });
</script>
```

i tried the same on JSFiddle and it works without any issue , my version for flatpikr is 4.6.9 but although using another cdn i  nothing changes .

Note : i deleted in every test  the cache so i m sure that js is changed